# Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I just installed VS2010 and I want to connect to TFS, But I don't have any team explorer options.

I searched for Team Explorer and I found this [link](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2009/05/18/connecting-vs2010-to-tfs-2008.aspx) that states that Team Explorer comes preinstalled in VS2010 Team Suit.

I downloaded VS2010 Pro and don't have team explorer and can't find it anywhere.

Any ideas? Tips?

Thanks

Comment: What's even more confusing is now they have "Team Explorer" and "Team Explorer Everywhere", which appear to be two completely different packages.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think there's been a misunderstanding down MS naming conventions.

All versions of Visual Studio 2010 have the ability to conenct to TFS built in, there is no longer a separate install (what was previously called Team Explorer).

What the Ultimate edition gets with what is now called Team Explorer (codename Eaglestone) is a standalone rich client for accessing TFS.

Comment: This is correct. There are TWO "Team Explorer"s. (1) The View->Team Explorer menu opens a *window* that allows connection to TFS from all VS 2010 Professional/Premium/Ultimate editions. (2) The "Team Explorer" *product* is a standalone edition of Visual Studio that *only* contains the Team Explorer Window and some basic text/bitmap editing functionality (no langugae compilers).

Comment: @jason: Do I need to have a separate licence for this standalone team explorer product you mentioned. as currently I have VS2010 premium edition and I want to use it separate.

Comment: I have VS 2010 and "Team Explorer" doesn't appear in the view menu!

Answer (score 13):

If you downloaded VS2010 Pro...you didn't download a version that came with Team Explorer. You need to re-download VS2010 Team System. You can grab it from MSDN or download it from:

[Visual Studio 2010 Team System Beta 1 Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=85520793-68fc-4361-a8b6-dc2cff49c8d2&displaylang=en)

**UPDATE**

As of Beta 2, Microsoft renamed versions a little. TFS Connectivity is now included with 'Ultimate'.

Comment: I snagged ultimate and its included.  Glad I did, now.

Comment: Amen. As of Beta 2, TFS Functionality is included with Ultimate.

Comment: Update: As of the RTM, *all* Professional/Premium/Ultimate editions now have the Team Explorer window built in.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like Team Explorer is also available as a separate download. The VS 2010 Beta 2 version is here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=CA86215B-A824-44E7-B4C3-982C7ECEA46D&displaylang=en

Answer (score 8):

The RTM version of Team Explorer is here: [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 - ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FE4F9904-0480-4C9D-A264-02FEDD78AB38&displaylang=en)

Comment: Note that this link is for a standalone Visual Studio Shell that contains the Team Explorer *window* and very little else. Access to TFS via the Team Explorer *window* is available in all Professional/Premium/Ultimate editions of VS 2010 RTM.

Comment: Right, it's a lightweight install and the functionality for a developer is limited. We found it useful to give to PMs who only need to review Work Items, Documents and Reports.

Comment: so what's the licensing on this?

Comment: Please tell what is the separate licensing of it.

Answer (score 7):

VS2010 Pro is a different release from VS2010 Team Suit and it doesn't contain anything that has to do with TFS. If you want to connect to TFS you need to get the VS2010 Team Suit release.

This has been the norm ever since VS2005.

Comment: In 2005 and 2008 there is a separate install package that installs Team Explorer on top of an existing VS Pro install

Comment: I don't think this package exists for the beta, I assume it will exist for the final release but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Its called "ultimate" or "premium".

Comment: VS 2008 Team Edition does *not* include Team Explorer! It's a separate install.

Comment: @craig's right - one of the most mind boggling confusing things MS ever did :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can download Visual Studio Team Explorer (or the command line tools) from the following:

1. <strike>[Team Explorer 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776)</strike>
2. <strike>[Team Explorer 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656)</strike>
3. [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4240)
4. [Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16338)
5. [Team Explorer 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7203)