# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have Team explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed in my system. I'm surprised to find both Team explorer option and Team menu is not available. I googled and some found links provided below to install Team explorer in VS2010 but nothing worked out.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915995/visual-studio-2010-team-explorer)
[Link2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4240)

I need team explorer option/Tools menu in VS2010. Any suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Solution installer for Visual studio 2010 can be downloaded from the below provided link

https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Team-Explorer-2010/3001-2383_4-75450987.html

Install the setup.exe file. Once the installation is done, restart the Visual studio and you could find the Team menu/team explorer.