# Use Git locally against Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control server

Tags: git, tfvc

A customer decided to use the centralized [Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/overview?view=azure-devops) (TFVC) for source code control. I myself prefer [Git](https://git-scm.com/) and [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/). I found some older information addressing Git as a local client for TFVC (and many recommendations on migration of TFVC to Git, which is not possible in this case), but they tell it's very difficult and painful to work with.

I'm very familiar with Git and TortoiseGit on Windows, but have no experience with TFVC. Is there a similar solution like git-svn for the TFVC part? What is necessary to install to get this "connection" done?

Comment: Take a look at [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/).

Comment: Thanks,  @ChristianHeld. It says I shall install a particular version of Team Explorer as well, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915995/visual-studio-2010-team-explorer) Team Explorer is already part if Visual Studio since 2010. What's up with 2019?

Comment: The Team Explorer that comes with Visual Studio should be fine. I did not install another Team Explorer version when I used git-tfs to migrate a repo from tvc to git with VS2017. IMHO it should work with VS2019, too. I have not used git-tfs after we migrated to git.