# Is Team Explorer 2010 free?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, version-control, team-explorer

We are planning to migrate our VS2005 Professional project to VS2010 Professional. We are also looking into source control option, we have a Dev Essential subscription and wondering if we can use TFS or Team Explorer with VS2010 Professional?

Is Team Explorer 2010 free? We are planning to install it on our test web server and for database we will use our test db server. Both servers are on 2008.

Comment: as @walter-qian-msft suggested in his answer, why do you still use unsupported TFS 2010? You should use at least TFS 2017.

Comment: You should consider investing in modern tools instead "upgrading" to tools that are already over a decade old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if we can use TFS or Team Explorer with VS2010 Professional?

Yes. There are three levels of client support for different versions of Visual Studio and Team Explorer.  You can refer to this document about [Azure DevOps client compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops-2020#visual-studio-and-team-explorer). Please also refer to this ticket about [Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915995/visual-studio-2010-team-explorer).

> Is Team Explorer 2010 free?

Yes, you can download Team Explorer 2010 for free. But users of Team Foundation Server will typically need a client access license (CAL). See the [licensing white paper](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Visual-Studio-Licensing-Whitepaper-Aug-2020.pdf) (Pages 25 and 28) for details. You can also refer to this [blog](https://edsquared.com/team-explorer-included-in-visual-studio-2010-installation-5104ad594c85).

By the way, Visual Studio 2010 has ended its lifecycle. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2010) for details. So if possible, I may suggest you consider using the latest version of VS, for example, VS 2019. It is stable and powerful, of course, this may cause some compatible issues, and just as a suggestion.

Comment: Is VSTS is free for small projects (4 users) ?

Comment: @user1263981 Yes. You can assign Stakeholder or Basic access level to users. Stakeholder is a free access level. Basic is free for the first 5 users, and paid for 6 or more users. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=azure-devops) for more details. Please note that this is VSTS (Azure DevOps Services) and not TFS (Team Foundation Server) or Azure DevOps Server. Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/about-azure-devops-services-tfs?view=azure-devops).

Comment: @user1263981 Does the answer resolved your question?  If yes, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).